# create map when you have a vector of keys and values

Tags: clojure

I'm sure this is easy but i suspect i'll have a lot of little questions on the road to idomatic clojure. Maybe I missed something but looking at the clojure map page, I didn't find a solution.

Given two vectors (one of keys other of values) how do you efficiently (key word!) create a map from key to value?

The keys and values are below:

```
(:year :month :day) (core/split "2013-02-18" #"-")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The natural solution is to use `zipmap`:

```
(zipmap [:year :month :day] (clojure.string/split "2013-02-18" #"-"))
;= {:day "18", :month "02", :year "2013"}
```

For a small map like this it is actually pretty efficient. For a larger map, you'd want `zipmap` to use transients, which it currently doesn't. There's a ticket for that in JIRA, with my patch attached: [CLJ-1005](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1005).

Of course it's simple enough to include the transient-enabled `zipmap` in one's own codebase and use it in preference to the one in `clojure.core`. This is a pretty important thing to do if you're zipping up larger maps.

The code can be copied over from the patch or from the ClojureScript core library, which does use transients in its `zipmap`; here a link to the [ClojureScript source](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/r1844/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L6195) as of release 1844 (this particular function can be used in Clojure with no changes).

Comment: Great answer thank you.  Clojure is a blast so far, I feel myself being released from the visors of OO programming...

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [zipmap](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/zipmap)